# How to get this postgres group by date count include days with 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this Postgres query to select all users from the last 30 days and group by count.

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', last_30_day).count(:order => 'DATE(created_at) ASC', :group => ["DATE(created_at)"])
```

The problem is that is returning like this

```
2014-01-15     6
2014-01-13     2
2014-01-09     1
```

And I would like to get the days with cero results as well like this

```
2014-01-15     6
2014-01-14     0
2014-01-13     2
2014-01-12     0
2014-01-11     0
2014-01-10     0
2014-01-09     1
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

To expound on @mu_is_too_short answer you can do it using `generate_series` like so:

```
SELECT dt.series, COUNT(u.created_at)
FROM users u
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    GENERATE_SERIES( (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 day')::date, NOW()::date, '1 day')::date
    AS series
) AS dt 
on DATE_TRUNC('month', u.created_at) = dt.series
GROUP BY dt.series
ORDER BY dt.series DESC
```

Which yields like:

```
  series   | count
------------+-------
 2014-01-08 |     0
 2014-01-07 |     0
 2014-01-06 |     0
 2014-01-05 |     0
 2014-01-04 |     0
 2014-01-03 |     0
 2014-01-02 |     0
 2014-01-01 |     1
 2013-12-31 |     0
```

Futhermore the ActiveRecord syntax for this is quite ugly, your best bet is to write it in the pure SQL above and just retrieve your raw results. Something like:

```
sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT dt.series, COUNT(u.created_at)
    FROM users u
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
        GENERATE_SERIES( (NOW() - INTERVAL '30 day')::date, NOW()::date, '1 day')::date
        AS series
    ) AS dt 
    on DATE_TRUNC('month', u.created_at) = dt.series
    GROUP BY dt.series
    ORDER BY dt.series DESC
SQL

records = User.connection.select_all(sql)
records.each do |record|
  puts record['series']
end
```

Because `<<-SQL` is interpolated you can use variables inside to adjust your query.

Answer (score 3):

With a short list like you have, the easiest thing would be to generate a hash with the desired dates:

```
zeros = 30.downto(0)
          .map { |n| n.days.ago.to_date.iso8601 }
          .each_with_object({}) { |d, h| h[d] = 0 }
```

and then merge the database's results into it:

```
@users = zeros.merge(User.where(...).count(...))
```

If you wanted to do it all inside the database then you could OUTER JOIN with a derived table generated from [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html):

```
select dt.d, count(*)
from (
    select current_date - 30 + i
    from generate_series(0, 30) as gs(i)
) as dt(d)
left join user u on date(u.created_at) = dt.d
```

Trying to get AR to produce that SQL would be a bit messy and probably not worth it for only a month's worth of data.